# Simple Javascript test not being exectuted

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using Notepad++ to write a simple JavaScript program. I tried to run it with Firefox but the page was blank. I saved it as a HTML file but still nothing. Where am I going wrong?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 

<title>Exercise 1 </title>

</head>

<body>

<script type = “text/javascript”>
var myName = "type your name!!";
document.write("Hello World");
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try finding the code in Windows Explorer / Finder / Files, then dragging it into your web browser. Still a blank page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These look like left quote/right quote characters:

```
<script type = “text/javascript”>
               ^               ^
```

They should be regular double-quote characters `<script type="text/javascript">`, or you can leave them out entirely, as all browsers default to using Javascript:

```
<script>
</script>
```

Additionally, it is not recommended to use document.write any longer. You should use some of the [DOM manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) methods available instead.

Comment: What I find curious is why the fancy quotes were on the script tag and not in the JavaScript code. My guess is that the script tag along with the rest of the boilerplate was copied from elsewhere while the code was typed in manually. Especially in the case of a simple text editor such as Notepad++ (or even Notepad), the only way one could enter fancy quotes by hand is by using alt key codes or some sort of macro (or even charmap.exe).

Comment: While learning OP might have copied `<script type=“text/javascript”>` because that's we all do in learning stage.

Comment: Ok i understand. The <script> text was copy and pasted from a example so I didnt write it out. Thanks all who replied.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out you are using the wrong type of quotes. Note that you can download jshint for notepad++ which can be very useful as it catches these types of bugs before you run. At the time of writing this answer, you can get it from sourceforge [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jslintnpp/). It includes jslint and jshint.

> JSHint is a community-driven tool to detect errors and potential
>   problems in JavaScript code and to enforce your team's coding
>   conventions. It is very flexible so you can easily adjust it to your
>   particular coding guidelines and the environment you expect your code
>   to execute in.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @helb - I have added the quote from the jshint site. Other than that, the link is a jshint plugin for notepad++ that will find these kinds of problems. There is no source or real information beyond what the tool does that I can provide. If the link becomes stale they could always search for jshint in google.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon - I am neither seeking to critique nor request clarification from the author. If they followed the advice in my answer they would have caught the problem.